# Extract if-elsif conditions according to their levels

Tags: perl

```
if (CONDITION_1) {
    if (CONDITION_A) {
        a = 1;
    }
}
elsif (CONDITION_2) {
    if (CONDITION_B) {
        if (CONDITION_i) {
            a = 2;
        }
        elsif (CONDITION_ii) {
            a = 3;
        }
        endif
    }
    endif
}
endif
```

I want to extract the conditions out as strings, and print them out according to their levels like:

```
CONDITION_1
CONDITION_1//CONDITION_A
CONDITION_2
CONDITION_2//CONDITION_B
CONDITION_2//CONDITION_B//CONDITION_i
CONDITION_2//CONDITION_B//CONDITION_ii
```

How should I code it recursively in Perl, as the real file might have more than 3 levels of if-else block? I cant manage to get the logic correct. Many thanks.

----------EDIT----------

I have figured out the logic behind it, here's my working code:

```
my (%cond, $lvl);
open my $fh, '<', $file or die;
while (<$fh>) {
    if (/if\s\((\w+)\)/) {
        $lvl++;
        push @{ $cond{$lvl} }, $1;
        for my $i (1 .. $lvl) {
            print "${ $cond{$i} }[-1]";
            print "//" if $i != $lvl;
        }
        print "\n";
    }
    elsif (/elsif\s\((\w+)\)/) {
        push @{ $cond{$lvl} }, $1;
        for my $i (1 .. $lvl) {
            print "${ $cond{$i} }[-1]";
            print "//" if $i != $lvl;
        }
        print "\n";
    }
    elsif (/else/) {
        push @{ $cond{$lvl} }, 'else';
        for my $i (1 .. $lvl) {
            print "${ $cond{$i} }[-1]";
            print "//" if $i != $lvl;
        }
        print "\n";
    }
    elsif (/endif/) {
        $lvl--;
    }
}
close $fh;
```

Comment: what is the "something"?  to do this reliably, you need to be able to parse everything, not just the things you want.

Comment: They are just declaration of defines like `define CONSTANT 3`. However, the contents of if blocks are not important as i only need to extract out the conditions. Sorry about that.

Comment: is the indentation always absolutely consistent then?  and always spaces, not tabs?

Comment: The indentation are not always consistent, depends on each person's coding style. the perl script is suppose to work with any nested if blocks. Sorry i didnt get your question just now. (Edited: Consistent indentation)

Comment: if it can't be parsed solely on indentation, then it is important to know what other things can appear in the grammar, like comments or quoted strings, that may make things that look like if/else/elseifs not actually be them or make things match up differently

Comment: I see what you are concerned about. Quoted strings and comments were taken care. And for my case, the file i'm working on only exists if/elsif/else/endif. The example I created above is just to show the idea behind what I'm doing, as I need help for the logic of this script. And I will try to understand and learn from the answers.

Answer (score 0):

This is thoroughly untested code, but a would be my spin on the situation using your "if-elsif-endif" sample construct.  I think conceptually it's right, but would need some dev and debug time:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my $in = "if-elsif-endif_feed";
my $out = "if-elsif-endif_parsed";

my $level;
my $condition;
my @levels;
my @conditions;

open IN, "<", $in or die "IN: $!\n";
open OUT, ">", $out or die "OUT: $!\n";

while (<IN>) {
    if ( $_ =~ m/^[elsif].*$/i ) {
        if ( $_ =~ m/endif/i ) {
            next;
        } else {
            $level = 1;
            ($condition) = $_ =~ m/[elsif].*\((.*)\).*$/;
            push @levels, $level;
            push @conditions, $condition;
        }
    } elsif ( $_ =~ m/^\s+[elsif].*$/i ) {
        if ( $_ =~ m/endif/i ) {
            next;
        } else {
            $level++;
            ($condition) = m/\s+[elsif].*\((.*)\).*$/;
            push @levels, $level;
            push @conditions, $condition;
        }
    } elsif ( $_ =~ m/\s+\}.*$/ ) {
        $condition = "end";
        push @levels, $level;
        push @conditions, $condition;
        $level--;
    } elsif ( $_ =~ m/\}.*$/ ) {
        $condition = "end";
        $level = 1;
        push @levels, $level;
        push @conditions, $condition;
    } else {
        next;
    }
}

my $numlevels = @levels;
my $i;
my $curlevel;
my $curcond;
my $string;
my $stringc;

for ($i = 0; $i <= $numlevels; $i++) {
    $curlevel = $levels[$i];
    $curcond = $conditions[$i];


    if ( $curlevel == 1 ) {
        if ( $curcond ne "end" ) {
            $string = "$curcond";
            print "$string\n";
            print OUT "$string\n";
        } else {
            $string = undef;
        }
    } elsif ($curlevel > 1 ) {
        if ( $curcond ne "end" ) {
            $stringc = $string;
            if (( $levels[++$i] == $curlevel ) && ( $conditions[++$i] eq "end" )) {
                $string .= "\/\/$curcond";
                print "$string\n";
            } elsif (( $levels[++$i] == $curlevel ) && ( $conditions[++$i] ne "end" )) {
                $string = $stringc;
            }
        } elsif ( $curcond eq "end" ) {
            print "$string\n";
            print OUT "$string\n";
        }
    }
}
```

So in the first part, you're basically looping through the file and capturing the level and condition info into arrays, with level being independent of the # of spaces.  Them, you're parsing the arrays into the appropriate strings and printing them in the proper place.

Hope that helps!!

Comment: Why the down vote?  Am I that far off?  At least leave some feedback if you feel the need to down vote my answer...

Comment: Sorry, it is truly not me that downvoted you. I have upvoted it. Thanks for your answer anyway, I took some ideas as reference =)

Comment: Thank you, coff_ee, I appreciate it.  I hope it at least helped somewhat!  :)